# Editing hosts file to block sites isn't working for 4chan, how do I fix it?

Tags: gedit, hosts

I have blocked quite a few sites by editing the hosts file but have just discovered that this method doesn't seem to be working for 4chan.

The method I'm using is sudo -i gedit /etc/hosts and then of course adding 0.0.0.0 4chan.org (as well as 0.0.0.0 boards.4chan.org, 0.0.0.0 4channel.org and 0.0.0.0 127.0.0.1, the IP you get when you ping the site). The strange thing is that I've had 4chan blocked for a while using this method and it had been working fine.

The only thing I can think of is this. 4chan has a new verification system of some sort. Go to 4chan.org and you briefly land on a page that says "making sure the connection is secure" or something to that effect (sometimes the page asks you to complete a CAPTCHA too) before you're directed to the main site. Perhaps that's interfering with blocking the site in the hosts file somehow?

Or could it be a problem on ubuntu's end? I've had issues with blocking sites with the hosts file before (using the terminal didn't work and there was another site which I'd blocked by editing the hosts file with gedit that I was also able to access until recently, not sure what fixed it). What makes me doubt that it is something specific to ubuntu is that I asked a friend running windows 10 to try blocking 4chan with the hosts file and it doesn't work for them either.

If anyone has any ideas I'd really appreciate hearing them. Apologies if I've made any obvious mistakes or misstated things, I'm very much not a technical person.